# Tcl expressions with hex numbers?

Tags: hex, expression, tcl

The Tcl `expr` function supports arguments written in hex notation: operands which begin with `0x` are treated as integers written in hex form.

However the return value of `expr` is always in decimal form: `expr 0xA + 0xA` returns `20`, not `0x14`.

Is there a way to tell `expr` to return the hex representation?
Is there a Tcl function which converts decimal representation to hex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the [`format`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/format.htm) command is what you're after:

```
format 0x%x [expr {0xa + 0xa}]  ;# ==> 0x14
```

Comment: It seems the binary case doesn't work: `format %b 0xa` fails instead or returning `1010`.

Comment: Tcl's `format` does not have a "%b" (see the link to the documentation in my answer). You can find Tcl code to return a string of binary digits [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_digits#Tcl). Tcl 8.6 (still in beta) DOES have a "%b" formatter.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to elaborate on the glenn's post to make things more clear for Vahagn.

`expr` does not return its result in one representation or another, instead, it returns a value in some suitable internal format (an integer, a big integer, a floating point value etc). What you see doing your testing is just Tcl interpreter converting what `expr` returned to an appropriate textual form using a *default* conversion to a string which, for integers, naturally uses base 10.

This conversion takes place in your case solely because you wanted to display the value returned by `expr`, and displaying of (any) values naturally tends to convert them to strings if they are "printed"—to a terminal, to a [tkcon](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net)'s window etc.

By using `format` you enforce whatever string representation you want instead of the default one.  Since `format` already returns a value which is a string internally, no conversion takes place when it's printed.